# How to list all of feature class in SDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class

I am getting a problem: my SDE contains some feature classes, but after using the statement:

```
var namesEnum = workspace.DatasetNames[esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass];
var tempName = namesEnum.Next(); // get value null
```

The value of tempName is Null, but it is ok if I use esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureDataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have answered your own question, your FeatureClasses must all be in FeatureDatasets.

In help for this method it says:

> In order to get the feature class names within a feature dataset, the
>   application needs to get the FeatureClassNames property on the
>   top-level feature dataset name returned by the workspace.